# Access denied issue on form builder?

Tags: magento-1.9, user-roles, acl

I have used config.xml for permission allow to user. Here are my code. But i am getting error access denied for new user. Please suggest me where is i am wrong.

```
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <formbuilder module="formbuilder">
            <title>Form Builder</title>
            <sort_order>77</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="formbuilder">
                    <title>Manage Forms</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>formbuilder/adminhtml_formbuilder</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </formbuilder>
    </menu>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <formbuilder>
                <file>formbuilder.xml</file>
            </formbuilder>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <formbuilder module="formbuilder">
                        <title>Form Builder</title>
                        <sort_order>77</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items module="formbuilder">
                                <title>Manage Forms</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>formbuilder/adminhtml_formbuilder</action>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </formbuilder>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

In controller we are used this code

```
protected function _isAllowed(){  return true;}
```

Comment: clear cache logout and relogin and try again

Comment: @fschmengler i have update  xml now. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

The `<acl>`  element should not be inside `<adminhtml>`  but directly inside `<config>`.

Otherwise it looks right, just that the action node `<action>formbuilder/adminhtml_formbuilder</action>` is not necessary in `<acl>`, only in `<menu>`.

After changing the XML file, clean your configuration cache, log out of the admin panel and log back in (that's because the ACL is only loaded on login).

Comment: Let me check :)

Comment: its not working for me. Can you sent me demo xml for permission if you have any? thanks

Comment: @Aman add this method in admin controllers:  `protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}`

Comment: @Aman I explained it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45141/how-to-add-acl-in-custom-module-in-magento/136254#136254 - but if you want a full example, just look at any of the `etc/adminhtml.xml` files of the Magento core modules.

Comment: We need to create aminhtml.xml or we are  use this code in  config.xml

Comment: Convention is to use `adminhtml.xml`, but since both files are merged anyway, you can still use `config.xml`